# Conditional Insert Statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I would like to achieve the following in a MySQL insert statement.

Say for example there is a MySQL statement like below:

```
Insert into table_name (col1, col2, col3) values (val1, val2, val3, val4);
```

What I want to achieve is: If val3 is empty, then val4 should be inserted to col3. If val4 is empty, then val3 should be inserted to col3.

How can I achieve this in a MySQL insert statement?

Comment: The amount of columns and the amount of values must match strictly.

Comment: What happen when val3 & val4 are both empty or both have value?

Answer (score 3):

If "If `val3` is empty" means "`val3` is NULL" then

```
Insert into table_name (col1, col2, col3) values (val1, val2, COALESCE(val3, val4));
```

If `val3` is not NULL - this value will be inserted, and `val4` will be ignored anycase.
If `val3` is null, then `val4` will be inserted, even it is NULL.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I have told that I describe the case when *"val3 is empty" means "val3 is NULL"* only. Because shown query text will produce syntax error always, and MySQL does not support skipping values (like `(1,,2)`), OP tells about some upper-level language where "empty" value means skipped value in a call - in this case NULL is transferred to MySQL server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a case statement to check for null or '' string

```
Insert into table_name (col1, col2, col3) 
values (val1, val2, case when val3 is null or val3 = '' then val4 else val3 end);
```